# How to change a php variables content with html textbox

Tags: php, html

I'm  wondering how to change a PHP variable, which is called `$ID` by typing something in a textbox but without transferring the page to a new page.

So, for example if my `$ID` is 1 and I type in the textbox 2, press submit then my variable `$ID` turns into 2.

Comment: If you want to do that without a page refresh, look up AJAX.

Comment: My bet is that you're confusing PHP and JavaScript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could post the value using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), but the variable will lose its state anyway between requests. You're better off saving it as a session variable:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['ID']=$_POST['ID'];
```